# Timestamp error with VTT subtitles downloaded using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I used FFMPEG to download subtitles with the following command:

ffmpeg -i "https://sdn-global-streaming-cache-3qsdn.akamaized.net/stream/9378/files/18/12/1068412/9378-HWQKVTXrYyxwncZq.ism/9378-HWQKVTXrYyxwncZq-textstream_eng=1000.m3u8?mime=mp4&source=html5" subs.srt

Every caption in the resulting SRT file starts at 00:00:00,000 which means that all the subs are shown at the same time. I tried downloading the file in the original VTT format instead of SRT but it makes no difference. The clock is reset to zero for each caption.

Is there a solution?